# Speedup copy between 2 arrays in a C loop

Tags: c, arrays, performance, macros

- I need to copy some values from an array A to an array B.
- The number of items to copy is stored in the uint32_t **r3** variable.
- Each index of the value to copy from a to b is encoded in the uint32_t **next** variable.
- Each index cannot be more than 255 (8 bits) so 4 indices are encoded into the uint32_t variable **ip** and decoded using a OPCODE_GET_FOUR8bit macro.

Data is read from array A using the macro STACK_GET(index) and it is written to array B using the macro SETVALUE(index, value).

My current copy loop is:

```
register uint32_t nloop = (r3+3)>>2; // efficient way to round r/4 upward
register idx = 0;
while (nloop) {
    uint32_t next = *ip++;
    OPCODE_GET_FOUR8bit(next, uint32_t p1, uint32_t p2, uint32_t p3, uint32_t p4);

    if (r3) { SETVALUE(rwin+idx, STACK_GET(p1)); --r3;
        if (r3) { SETVALUE(rwin+idx+1, STACK_GET(p2)); --r3;
            if (r3) { SETVALUE(rwin+idx+2, STACK_GET(p3)); --r3;
                if (r3) { SETVALUE(rwin+idx+3, STACK_GET(p4)); --r3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    --nloop; idx+=4;                    
}
```

Which involves 4 **r3** decrement and 4 if statements inside the loop (because I know in advance the number of items to copy using r3 but the loop encodes 4 indexes at a time).

I wondering if there is a way to speedup this performance critical loop.

Comment: Only a comment, not an answer: do not round up, just truncate (r3>>2). Then do all the loop without testing for r3, since you know it will be greather than 0. Then, after the loop, do the 3 r3 testings that are remaining. This way you will save 4 ifs per loop. Also do not do --r3, just do at the end of each iteration r3-=4

Comment: What do all those macros do?  If there's anything even slightly non-trivial, then they may well be the rate-limiting step. Could you tell us why `memcpy` isn't suitable for this?

Comment: For example, when r3 is 2, nloop is 1 and ip will contain 2 indexes and 2 garbages encode, that's the reason why I need to decrement and check for r3 4 times inside the loop, otherwise 2 garbages will be copied.

Comment: memcpy is not suitable since p1,p2,p3,p4 can be non continuos indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously know when you are on the last `nloop` iteration; all of the previous ones do not need **ANY** `if`'s at all.

[Added code sample]

```
register idx = rwin;
while (r3 > 3) {
    uint32_t next = *ip++;
    OPCODE_GET_FOUR8bit(next, uint32_t p1, uint32_t p2, uint32_t p3, uint32_t p4);

    SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p1));
    SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p2));
    SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p3));
    SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p4));
    r3 -= 4;
}
if (r3) {
    uint32_t next = *ip++;
    OPCODE_GET_FOUR8bit(next, uint32_t p1, uint32_t p2, uint32_t p3, uint32_t p4);
    SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p1)); --r3;
    if (r3) {
        SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p2)); --r3;
        if (r3) {
            SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p3)); --r3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Either "great minds think alike", or "fools seldom differ". ;)

Comment: @Roddy - I saw your comment right when I was saving my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your macros are not affecting the performance (although I rather doubt that). First, handle the 'easy' cases with a simple loop. No conditionals.

```
register idx;

for (idx=rwin; r3 >= 4; r3 -=4)
{
    OPCODE_GET_FOUR8bit(*ip++, uint32_t p1, uint32_t p2, uint32_t p3, uint32_t p4);

    SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p1));
    SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p2));
    SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p3));
    SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p4));
}
```

Then, follow that with the 'complex' case for the last (up to three) values. `r3` can only be 0, 1, 2 or 3 now. If it's zero, we're all done.

```
 if (r3 >=1 ) 
   SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p1));
 if (r3 >= 2)
   SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p2));
 if (r3 >=3 ) 
   SETVALUE(idx++, STACK_GET(p3));
```

If you need further speedup, it may be faster to assemble and write a single 32-bit value within the main loop, rather than writing four 8-bit ones. Without knowing what your macro does, it's not possible to suggest code for that.